# Angular Unit Test for ChangeDetectorRef Detect Changes

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write a unit test for the `ChangeDetectorRef` but is returning `Expected Spy but got undefined`. What could be the issue? Do I need to `spy` or `mock` the `detectChanges` method?

**TestComponent**

```
export class TestComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
        constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}    
}

ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

**TestComponentSpec**

```
   beforeEach(async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule(
      { providers: [ChangeDetectorRef] }
      )
   })

describe('ngAfterViewChecked', () => {
    it('should call detect changes', (inject([ChangeDetectorRef],  (changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) => {

      component.ngAfterViewChecked();

      expect(changeDetectorRef.detectChanges).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })));
  });
```